# OSMdroid don't refresh after fragment replacing

Tags: android-fragments, replace, osmdroid

I'm working with OSMDroid and fragments. The problems start when i noticed that saveInstance method is not calling when I replace a fragment, so I saw in another question this hack to prevent the view to be re-inflate.

```
if (_view != null) { 
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) _view.getParent();
    parent.removeView(_view);
    return _view; 
}
```

After that, when my osmdroid map fragment is again visible and this portion of code is executed the osm map stop refreshing the screen. I can zoom in and zoom out but the screen is never refreshed. However, the events (tap, zoom or scroll) are still working.

I have no idea what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getMapView().invalidate();`